# Multiple statement conditions using OR AND within the query

Tags: sql-server, condition, prepared-statement

I have this survey table and I'm trying to gather the information of userid
who answer **Strongly agree** to the question of **I'm trying to watch my 
weight** OR **I love drinking Coffee Black** AND must have answer **Agree** 
OR **Neutral** OR **Strongly Disagree**  to these questions **I thrive when 
a deadline is close**  and **I'm all about trying something new**.

```
UserId                QUESTION                               Answer
 1010            I am trying to watch my weight           Strongly Agree
 1120            I thrive when a deadline is close        Strongly Agree
 1120           I'm all about trying something new        Neutral
 2025            I'm all about trying something new       Agree
 3024            I love drinking Coffee Black             Strongly Disagree
 3024            I'm all about trying something new       Agree
```

The queries that I tried to write keeps returning the questions that I 
 didn't write.This might not be the best way write such query but I'm 
 learning on how to properly write those. Any help would be appreciated.

```
 SELECT userid_
  ,QUESTION 
  ,answer
   FROM [Survey_2019]]

Where QUESTION  = 'I'm trying to watch my weight'  AND
    Answer =  'Strongly agree'
  OR
      QUESTION    = 'I love drinking Coffee Black
  AND 
 Answer =  'Strongly agree'

AND 

 QUESTION= 'I thrive when a deadline is close'
  AND ANSWER= 'Agree' 
OR 'Neutral' OR 'Strongly Disagree'
```

Comment: Always use parentheses when combining AND and OR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have this survey table and I'm trying to gather the information of userid who answer Strongly agree to the question of I'm trying to watch my weight OR I love drinking Coffee Black AND must have answer Agree OR Neutral OR Strongly Disagree to these questions I thrive when a deadline is close and I'm all about trying something new.

Simplified:

```
          [     A:a        ON     (Q:a/b)   ]
    AND   [  (A:b/c/d)     ON       Q:c     ] 
    AND   [  (A:b/c/d)     ON       Q:d     ]
```

In SQL:

```
SELECT UserId
FROM Survey_2019
GROUP BY UserId
HAVING SUM (CASE WHEN Question IN ('a', 'b') AND Answer = 'a' THEN 1 END) > 0
   AND SUM (CASE WHEN Question = 'c' AND Answer IN ('b', 'c', 'd') THEN 1 END) > 0
   AND SUM (CASE WHEN Question = 'd' AND Answer IN ('b', 'c', 'd') THEN 1 END) > 0
```

If you need separate records matched then use this SQL as CTE/subquery and select separate records from another copy of source table.

**UPDATE**

It seems that last 2 conditions may be combined into one using simplified condition

```
    AND   [  (A:b/c/d)     ON       Q:c/d     ]
```

But the problem is to ensure that all (2 in that case) questions  are mentioned. 
Yes, this is possible and can be performed using, for example

```
   AND COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN Question IN ('c','d') 
                            AND Answer IN ('b', 'c', 'd') 
                           THEN Question 
                           END) = 2
```

If you need to ensure that there is no a record with the question(s) in interest and the answer not in list, then use additional condition similar to

```
   AND COUNT(CASE WHEN Question IN ('c','d') 
                   AND Answer NOT IN ('b', 'c', 'd') 
                  THEN 1
                  END) = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

For a start: You are missing a number of parentheses (in any case).

Then: You need to combine different records into a single result. One way has been shown by  @Akina. Alternatively, you can run against two copies of the same table:

```
WITH
Part1 AS (
  SELECT
    userID
    , question
    , answer
  FROM Survey_2019
  WHERE
    question IN ('I am trying to watch my weight', 'I love drinking Coffee Black')
    AND
    answer = 'Strongly Agree'
),
Part2 AS (
  SELECT
    userID
    , question
    , answer
  FROM Survey_2019
  WHERE
    question IN ('I thrive when a deadline is close', 'I''m all about trying something new')
    AND
    answer IN ('Agree', 'Neutral', 'Strongly Disagree')
),
Overview (userID, question1, answer1, question2, answer2) AS (
  SELECT
    Part1.userID
    , Part1.question
    , Part1.answer
    , Part2.question
    , Part2.answer
  FROM Part1
  JOIN Part2
    ON Part1.userID = Part2.userID
)
SELECT
  * FROM Overview ORDER BY userID, question1, question2
;
```

See it in action: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/d9fcb/3) (Two records have been added to your sample data for an actual match.)

Akina's approach as detailed is more appropriate, if you care primarily for a list of users, for which the conditions are met. (But you can, of course, extend it along Akina's suggestion.) Mine provides directly all the details - but might become hard to swallow, if your data might be such as to produces multiple matches for a some user(s).

There is, however, a difference in Akina's an my reading of what is in **Part2** of my approach: Akina expects an answer to both of the questions, I'd be satisfied, if at least one of the was answered. - You'll know best, which one is correct. (Both SQL statements can be adjusted accordingly.)

Your table design is probably/hopefully still under development… ;-)

Please comment, if and as this requires adjustment / further detail.